# Dump erlang's beam files to filesystem

Tags: debugging, erlang, erlang-shell

I have a `remsh` to working Erlang application:

```
1> application:which_applications().
[{ssl,"Erlang/OTP SSL application","5.3.6"},
 {public_key,"Public key infrastructure","0.22.1"},
 {crypto,"CRYPTO","3.4.1"},
 {asn1,"The Erlang ASN1 compiler version 3.0.2","3.0.2"},
 {stdlib,"ERTS  CXC 138 10","2.2"},
 {kernel,"ERTS  CXC 138 10","3.0.3"}]
```

My question is: How can I save beam files to another place at the file system?

Answer (score 2):

For each module you want to save, call [`code:get_object_code/1`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/code.html#get_object_code-1) to get the module's object code as a binary, then use [`file:write_file/2`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/file.html#write_file-2) to save that binary to the file system.

Comment: By the way, will this solution works correct with modules, which were generated in runtime and have no image in filesystem?

Comment: Not sure what modules you have in mind, but even generated modules have to be compiled, so yes, it should work. For modules that are implemented as NIFs, you're obviously not going to get the native object code but rather the Erlang wrapper around it.

Comment: I have in mind situation when code compiled from abstract form, but not loaded from file. Like this https://github.com/eproxus/meck/blob/master/src/meck_code.erl#L69. According code_server implementation https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/maint/lib/kernel/src/code_server.erl#L380, this function only returns code for module which have thier filesystem image.

Comment: You're correct that code compiled from abstract form can't be retrieved using this approach, but it's not clear from the original question whether saving generated modules is a necessity. In general there's necessarily some agent in the system that's compiling the abstract form and loading the resulting beam, and if agent is another module, then saving that module means it can recreate any generated modules when it runs next time.